# Matplotlib: Coloring scatter plot based on relative density

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data set with x values contained in an array a and corresponding y values contained in an array b. I am plotting a scatter plot of this data set and have colored the points based on their density using scipy's gaussian_kde. The code looks something like:

```
    xy = np.vstack([x,y])
    z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

    # Sort the points by density, so that the densest points are plotted last
    idx = z.argsort()
    x, y, z = x[idx], y[idx], z[idx]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=50, edgecolor='')
    plt.show()
```

Now, I have another data set (contained in arrays c and d, corresponding to the x and y values of data set 2, respectively). I want to make a scatter plot of the FIRST data set still, but this time I would like to color code by the ratio of the spatial density of points in the FIRST data set to that of the spatial density of points in the second data set, so that I can see where objects in the first data set are relatively more prevalent. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Hey John- sorry for not phrasing the question well. Basically, I've plotted a scatter plot of my first data set and colored the points based on their spatial density. i.e: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sIg6N.png Now, I want to do the same thing (exact same scatter plot of the first data set), but instead color the points **based on the ratio of the spatial density of points in the first data set to that of points in a second data set**. That way, I can identify where my first data set is relatively denser than my second data set.

Comment: oh ok. if i understand it correctly, for each (x,y) in the first data set, you want it to be colored by c = (d1/d2) where d1 is density from 1st set and s2 is density from 2nd set. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep that's exactly right. I'm guessing there's a straightforward way to do it but I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: I see. If you have both density data, say `density1 = [0.2, 0.21, ...]` and `density2 = [0.3, 0.13, ...]`, and both have the same length, then you can do `density_ratio = [density1[i]/density2[i] for i in range(len(density1))]`

Comment: Yes, I tried this however I have many more points in my second data set than in my first data set (density1 and density2 are not the same length). Also, I believe this method assumes that density1[i] and density2[i] correspond to the same location (I.E it assumes they both refer to the density of their respective data sets at the SAME location).

Comment: now i see it. Your problem is not really with the plotting but with finding a way to compare densities of your different datasets. That's interesting.

Comment: Correct. Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the spatial density of the second data set.  Then calculate the ratio of the two densities.  Sort by the ratios and plot as before.

```
xy = np.vstack([x,y])
z = gaussian_kde(xy)(xy)

# spacial density of points in second data set
cd = np.vstack([c,d])
e = gaussian_kde(cd)(cd)

# ratio of density in the two data sets
r = z / e

# Sort the points by density ratio, so that the biggest ratios are plotted last
idx = r.argsort()
x, y, r = x[idx], y[idx], r[idx]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x, y, c=r, s=50, edgecolor='')
plt.show()
```

EDIT:  Sorry, I missed the comment that said the coordinates in the two data sets didn't correspond.  Try using `scipy.interpolate.interp2d()` to create a function that approximates the spatial density of the second data set.  Then use the function to estimate the density at the coordinates of the first data set.

```
from scipy import interpolate

# calculate spatial densities for the two data sets as above

f = interpolate.interp2d(c, d, e, kind='cubic')
r = z / f(x,y)
```

Now sort the ratios, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply -

Thanks for your response RootTwo! Unfortunately I ended up getting a memory error (I assume because my data sets are far too large). Is there a way to work around this - other than a better computer?

Comment: How big is your data set?  Perhaps you can do it in pieces. One program to do the interpolation and save the results to a file.  Now you have the parts to calculate the ratios, so a second program to do that and save it to a file.  Then a third to display the results.